# Prompt "yes" automatically in a script

Tags: bash, shell

I created a script for cleaning my system with `pacman` it works fine but I want to make response to *Yes/No* automatic.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Trash cleaning script by arch

sudo pacman -Sc && sudo paccache -r &&
yay -Sc &&
rmlint ~/ && sh ~/rmlint.sh &&
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/* &&
sudo pacman -Qtdq &&
sudo pacman -R $(pacman -Qtdq)
```

If I type in terminal `yes Y | sudo pacman -Sc` it works but if I add it to script

```
yes Y | sudo pacman -Sc && yes Y | sudo paccache -r &&
```

it gives response

```
Cache directory: /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
:: Do you want to remove all other packages from cache? [Y/n]
```

**Update**

It was my mistake for `Yay` *AUR packager* it works fine with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Trash cleaning script, by arch

yes Y | sudo pacman -Sc && sudo paccache -r &&
rmlint ~/ && yes | sh ~/rmlint.sh &&
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/* &&
sudo pacman -Qtdq &&
sudo pacman -R $(pacman -Qtdq)
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52277/pacman-option-to-assume-yes-to-every-question

Comment: @tripleee thanks but it still asks for confirmation

Comment: as I stated in terminal it works but running it with the script still asks for confirmation

Comment: I have found a mistake was `Yay` packager for AUR packages I had to `yes Y` for it as well but I thought it was caused by pacman